# how to use the result of 2 columns to create calculated column in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I’m stack with oracle sql
I have 4 columns
Course, gender, Total Enrolled, Total Pass (last 2 columns are calculated and does not exists in the database)

[image]

I’m trying to create 5th column to calculate the result of
(Total Pass / Total Enrolled) *100
I used the following sql

```
select Course , Gender",
       Count( case
       when Grade In('A+','A-','B','B+','B-','C','C+''F') then 'Total Enrolled with grades’ 
end ) as "Total_Enrolled",
       Count ( case
              when Grade In ('A+','A-','B','B+','B-','C','C+') then 'Pass'
       end ) as "Total_Pass"
  from Result
 group by 
          Course,
         Gender
 order by Course
```

Appreciate your help

thanks

Comment: You have no `grade` column. Also, please do not post images of data; post the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements to create that table/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . This sounds like conditional aggregation:

```
select Course, Gender,
       sum(case when Grade In ('A+', 'A-', 'B', 'B+', 'B-', 'C', 'C+', 'F') 
               then 1 else 0
           end) as Total_Enrolled
       sum(case when Grade In ('A+', 'A-', 'B', 'B+', 'B-', 'C', 'C+') 
               then 1 else 0
           end) as Total_Passed,
       ( sum(case when Grade In ('A+', 'A-', 'B', 'B+', 'B-', 'C', 'C+') 
                  then 1 else 0
              end) /
         sum(case when Grade In ('A+', 'A-', 'B', 'B+', 'B-', 'C', 'C+', 'F') 
                  then 1 
             end)
       ) as pass_ratio
from Result
group by Course, Gender
order by Course;
```

If you can filter in the `WHERE` clause, this is much simplified:

```
select Course, Gender,
       count(*) as Total_Enrolled
       sum(case when Grade In ('A+', 'A-', 'B', 'B+', 'B-', 'C', 'C+') 
               then 1 else 0
           end) as Total_Passed,
       avg(case when Grade In ('A+', 'A-', 'B', 'B+', 'B-', 'C', 'C+') 
                then 1
            end) as pass_ratio
from Result
where Grade In ('A+', 'A-', 'B', 'B+', 'B-', 'C', 'C+', 'F')
group by Course, Gender
order by Course;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to use your current query as a CTE and then reuse its calculated columns to get the final result:

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (  SELECT course,
                gender,
                COUNT (CASE
                          WHEN grade IN ('A+',
                                         'A-',
                                         'B',
                                         'B+',
                                         'B-',
                                         'C',
                                         'C+',
                                         'F')
                          THEN
                             'Total Enrolled with grades'
                       END) AS total_enrolled,
                COUNT (CASE
                          WHEN grade IN ('A+',
                                         'A-',
                                         'B',
                                         'B+',
                                         'B-',
                                         'C',
                                         'C+')
                          THEN
                             'Pass'
                       END) AS total_pass
           FROM result
       GROUP BY course, gender)
  SELECT course,
         gender,
         total_enrolled,
         total_pass,
         --
         (total_pass / total_enrolled) * 100 AS fifth_column
    FROM temp
ORDER BY course
```

Or, you could retype those `CASE`s and do it in the same query, but that's kind of difficult to read.

---

BTW, just like they said in *2001: A SpaceOdyssey*: "It's full of stars!", your code is full of errors. You should be more careful when posting contents here.

Comment: I'm new to sql, I will read more about your method to understand it more